# how to calculate number of values appeared in a string of list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

how to calculate  number of values  appeared in a string  of list of lists

```
a=['1000','10,8,6','9,76,9.0','1,2','']
```

required output

```
b=[1,3,3,2,0]
```

a is in my input, the required output is b
how to do it using python

Comment: please share your attempt.

Comment: Is it your homework? What part of the problem give you troubles?

Comment: I am unable to write code for it

Comment: @depperm this solution was shared by one of the user [len(s.split(',')) for s in a], but if the string is empty the count is been updated as1 instead of 0, how to tackle this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.